# Selecting line and column of all slices in Armadillo C++

Tags: c++, matlab, armadillo

Lets suppose I have a 3D matrix, like `A = ones(4,4,3)`. In MATLAB, if I want to define a variable at line 1 and column 1 for all the three dimensions I write:

```
A(1,1,:) = 0
```

How can I do the same in Armadillo? I have tried `A(1,1,span::all)`, but it did not work.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main()
{

    cube A = ones(4,4,3);
    A(1,1,span::all) = 0.0;

    cout << " A = " << endl << A << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"? What exactly happened? Please see [mcve]. I expect indexing to  start at 0 in C++ / Armadillo

Comment: Have you checked the arma doc? `cube(n_rows, n_cols, n_slices, fill_type)   memory is initialised` and `cube(n_rows, n_cols, n_slices)   memory is not initialised`

Comment: to solve the specific problem shown above, try this: `A(1,1,span::all).zeros();` otherwise `.fill(0)` should also work; also look at the docs for [cube views](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#subcube)

Comment: Use the `tube` sub cube view. If you want the top-left element of every slice to be 0, do `A.tube(0, 0) = 0.0`.